# Options in command-promt

Tags: command-prompt, yii2-advanced-app

This might be very basic, but I'm trying to use `init`, and should be able to choose one of the options bellow, but for some reason it seems like it goes back to the foot folder before I can answer. What can I do?

```
c:\wamp64\www\yii-application>init
Yii Application Initialization Tool v1.0

Which environment do you want the application to be initialized in?

  [0] Development
  [1] Production

  Your choice [0-1, or "q" to quit]
  Quit initialization.

c:\wamp64\www\yii-application>`
```

I have the same problem when I try to run migrate.

Comment: are you using windows ?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1463989/how-to-fix-windows-10-command-prompt-from-waiting-for-input

Comment: Yes, using windows 10. I followed the guide in the other question, but same result. It's like cmd promt does not wait for an answer

Comment: that is weird can you try with the git bash if you have it installed ?